# C++ function called in multiple places, how to refactor to accept a new argument?

Tags: c++, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have this function `f(MyType a, b)` and I want to it to become `f(MyType a, b, c)`. The problem is that `f` is called by multiple other functions (`g()`, `h()`, `i()`) which in turn are called by multiple other functions. I would need to pass the new argument `int c` down to all functions so they can pass it to `f()`.

I would like this:

```
int f(TypeA a, TypeB b);

int g(TypeA a, TypeB b) { 
    f(a, b);
}

int r(TypeA a, TypeB b) {
    g(a, b);
}
```

To become this:

```
int f(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c);

int g(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) { 
    f(a, b, c);
}

int r(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
    g(a, b, c);
}
```

How could I automate this? Is there any other elegant solution I'm not seeing?

Global mutable state is undesirable. I've considered creating a singleton class with setters and getters to avoid any unwanted side effects but MyType is already used in a lot of places and I would need to refactor those instead.

Comment: Have you considered making parameter `c` optional by providing a default value?

Comment: @jkb Unfortunately `MyType c` has to be initialized from command line arguments and 'f()` always needs it. There is no meaningful default value I could provide.

Comment: @user17732522 The arguments have different types, I will change the example to reflect that.

Comment: As far as recommendations for any tools, for this: this would not be an appropriate question for Stackoverflow -- software recommendations are not allowed here.

Comment: There's very little in C++ that's "automated".  Every instances of these parameters getting passed must be updated accordingly. It must be done. The only good news is that as long as every function's parameters need to change, change them to simply pass a single structure, by reference, with `a`, `b`, and `c`. Then, if you need to add `d` later it needs to be done in only one place. When the initial design proves to be unworkable, there is no alternative to paying the price and redesigning everything from scratch.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, that's unfortunate. I tried simply adding a new parameter but both GCC and Clang were the most unhelpful.

Comment: singleton class with setters and getters are essentially global state.

Comment: @appleapple That's true, keyword "mutable". I wouldn't let setters be called more than once, not very elegant but safer than a global.

Comment: Designing this from scratch a couple of options come to mind:1. Using template parameter packs&perfect forwarding, 2. introducing `using Parameter= std::tuple<TypeA,TypeB,TypeC>;` and going with `int f(Parameter const&); int g(Parameter const&); int r(Parameter const&);` as function signatures possibly using `std::apply` to invoke a function `int f(TypeA const&, TypeB const&, TypeC const&)`, 3. replacing the functions with functor templates and using a bit of template metaprogramming to keep the function signatures the same and creating the functions similar to `constexpr FImpl<Types> f;`

Comment: @fabian Thanks for your suggestion but I will probably go with a singleton class and make the fields immutable after the first call to `set_field()`. It's simpler and easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

If those functions need exactly the same arguments, why not grouping them into a struct?

```
struct Grouped
{
    TypeA a;
    TypeB b;
    TypeC c;
};
```

Once you do this, you just need to modify this 'Grouped' struct and no changes need to be done for the function signatures that are taking 'Grouped' struct as their arguments.

Comment: I would still need to change all functions, which is what I was trying to avoid. I will probably just go with a singleton class and make the fields immutable after set() is called once.